# Is there any way to solve equations like these?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any formula or method to solve equations like

$ ax + b^x = c $

Where $ a, b, c $ are real numbers

I mean exact solutions not approximations

Had any mathematician already worked on these?

Comment: How do you come up with this question? Is it an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: $b^x$ is not necessarily defined for an arbitrary real number.

Comment: It can have no, one or two roots depending on parameters.

Comment: @Jack It's my infance dream to solve this equation haha

Comment: This problem is not well defined as $b^x$ might have no definition.

Comment: Better get a better dream. This equation won't have a closed form solution.

Comment: Complex solutions are ok.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation

Comment: @EthanBolker Can you prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maple command `simplify(solve(a*x+b^x=c,x));` gives

$$\frac{c\ln(b)-a\,\mathrm{LambertW}\left(\dfrac{\ln(b)\,b^{c/a}}{a}\right)}{a\ln(b)}$$

So, there is a solution in terms of the Lambert W function, a special function. 
I don't know enough about it to explain it though but thought you might be interested.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a*x%2Bb%5Ex%3Dc+for+x) gives basically the same answer, given some restrictions on the constants. (Look at the next-to-last answer in the list.)

Comment: In particular, assuming that $a,b,c$ are real numbers and we want real-valued functions, we also need $a\ne 0$, $b>0$, and $b\ne 1$. (We might be able to allow some negative values of $b$ but that leads to tricky issues of the value of $b^z$ for some $z$.) The Lambert W function also sometimes gives no result, one result, or two results, so the same may be true of the final solution. If this question were not on hold I could show the derivation of the solution.

Comment: I edited your answer slightly to make the inner fraction larger and more readable. If you don't like this edit, just remove the `d` in the front of the `dfrac`.

Answer (score -1):

Solving $f(x)=c$ involves intersection of curve $y=f(x)$ and a line $y=c$. This intersection can be computed with a graphs $(x,f(x))$ and $(x,c)$ in 2d space in such way that points $(x,y)$ are in the intersection if $y=f(x)=c$.

Your problem also has $a$ and $b$ so it requires some currying:
 $(a,b) \rightarrow (x) \rightarrow f(x,a,b)$. I.e. once you know values of $a$ and $b$, the equation solving problem can be attempted.

Comment: `This intersection can be computed with a graphs` But the OP specifically asked for "*exact solutions not approximations*".

Comment: @dxiv: my first paragraph is basically definition of category theory equalizer  $\{x | f(x)=g(x)\}$ which is meant for solving this type of equations. It does not involve approximations.

Comment: So what is the `exact solution` you propose? If you don't have one, then sorry but the above is not answering OP's question.